# How to split a dataframe in groups with mutually excludent factors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, split

I'm struggling on how can I split my dataframe in 2 or more parts. I have a lot of columns and rows, but imagine a toy example:

```
test = data.frame(car = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "B", "C", "D"), value = c(5,4,3,5, 6, 6, 7 ,8 ,10))

#result
#  car value  group
#1   A     5  1
#2   A     4  1
#3   B     3  2
#4   C     5  1
#5   D     6  2
#6   E     6  2
#7   B     7  2
#8   C     8  1
#9   D    10  2
```

The only restriction that I need is:
The same car cannot be part of the same category, i.e., the same car, for example car `A`, it will appear in several lines of my real dataframe. Every time it occurs, it must have the same corresponding category, for example `group = 1`. The same group will have several different cars, but the same car can never be in different groups.

Any hint? I tried  `test %>% mutate(group = ntile(car, 4))` without success.

Comment: What do you mean by *same car not of same category*??

Comment: Also if you can have different cars in the same group, why not just have all the above cars in group1? Still your explanation is incomplete. Explain why/how car B,D are in group 2

Comment: @Onyambu, The same car, for example car `A`, it will appear in several lines of my real dataframe. Every time it occurs, it must have the same corresponding category, for example `group = 1`. The same group will have several different cars, but the same car can never be in different groups.

Comment: Then there is no uniques olution to this. ie depends how many groups you want. if you want 1 group, all the cars will be in the same group

Comment: @Onyambu, exactly. I'll try with 4 groups in the beginning to try to solve my real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `dplyr` approach:

```r
library(dplyr)

test = data.frame(car = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "B", "C", "D"), value = c(5,4,3,5, 6, 6, 7 ,8 ,10))

test %>% 
  mutate(group = 1 + match(car,car) %% 4) 

#>   car value group
#> 1   A     5     2
#> 2   A     4     2
#> 3   B     3     4
#> 4   C     5     1
#> 5   D     6     2
#> 6   E     6     3
#> 7   B     7     4
#> 8   C     8     1
#> 9   D    10     2
```

Comment: I have `11321` different cars, then I need some approach that includes more types of cars in the same group.

Comment: Well, @DR15, just replace my 4 by the desired number of groups!

Answer (score 1):

```
gr <- function(df, groups){
  g <- as.integer(factor(df[[1]])) %% groups
  df$groups <- as.integer(factor(g))
  df
}

gr(test, 1)
  car value groups
1   A     5      1
2   A     4      1
3   B     3      1
4   C     5      1
5   D     6      1

gr(test, 2)
  car value groups
1   A     5      2
2   A     4      2
3   B     3      1
4   C     5      2
5   D     6      1

gr(test, 3)
  car value groups
1   A     5      2
2   A     4      2
3   B     3      3
4   C     5      1
5   D     6      2
gr(test, 4)
  car value groups
1   A     5      2
2   A     4      2
3   B     3      3
4   C     5      4
5   D     6      1
```